# Kirchoff's law of thermal radiation states that if an object emits at a wavelength then it also absorbs at the same wavelength

Tags: thermal-radiation

What if the object is completely red, then when I heat this object would it emit a blackbody spectrum except for the red color?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is yes - to the extent that the heated object approximates a blackbody at all.

Thought experiment time.

Suppose you have your "red" object - which I will take to be an object that reflects all red light that is incident upon it, but absorbs everything else.

Now put it inside a blackbody cavity at some temperature and leave it to reach an equilibrium. Since it cannot absorb "red" radiation, it must achieve an equilibrium only through absorbing blackbody radiation in other parts of the spectrum. But if it reaches an equilibrium, it must radiate just as much energy in total as it absorbs.

The obvious solution is that it emits blackbody radiation itself, at all wavelengths apart from red.

But how could we test that - because another solution might be that it emits less than a blackbody at other-than-red wavelengths, whilst emitting some radiation in the red part of the spectrum?

Simple - we wrap the object in a filter which blocks red light. This does NOT change the amount of radiation absorbed at all.  With the filter around it, the object cannot lose any heat by radiating in the red part of the spectrum. Nevertheless it will reach a thermal equilibrium with the cavity - indicating that all the emitted radiation is coming out in the other-than-red wavelengths.

OK, but maybe the emitted radiation isn't a blackbody spectrum?

Simple - just try it again, but this time leave the red filter on and wrap *another* filter around it that blocks out some other waveband. This reduces the amount of absorbed radiation by exactly the amount of blackbody radiation in that filtered waveband. Nevertheless, the object will still reach thermal equilibrium with the cavity, indicating that the radiation it emits has also been reduced by exactly the same amount.

i.e. The emitted radiation in any waveband is the same as the absorbed radiation. Kirchoff's Law.